# MySQL: union query fails on MySQL 5.5, works on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, join, syntax, union

I'm having trouble with a stubborn MySQL query. It's a quite long and complex query, sorry about that. I really did my best to find it myself but I could use a hand here.

The following query is used to emulate a full outer join of column information in the information_schema, and column information in a table called nexedit_schema. The PHP variable $db contains the target database that contains the latter table.

The query actually successfully runs on my own server (MySQL version 5.1), but fails to run on a friend's server (MySQL version 5.5). It claims that I have a syntax error near "ON (schema_tables.db_table..."

I'm probably overlooking something really stupid. Anyone kind enough to help me out?

```
SELECT information_schema.tables.table_name, schema_tables.db_table, schema_tables.ne_page
  FROM information_schema.tables
  LEFT JOIN (
    (SELECT DISTINCT db_table, ne_page FROM {$db}.nexedit_schema)
    AS schema_tables)
  ON (schema_tables.db_table = information_schema.tables.table_name
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)
  WHERE information_schema.tables.table_schema = '{$db}'
    AND information_schema.tables.table_name NOT LIKE 'nexedit_%'

UNION

SELECT information_schema.tables.table_name, schema_tables.db_table, schema_tables.ne_page
  FROM information_schema.tables
  RIGHT JOIN (
    (SELECT DISTINCT db_table, ne_page FROM {$db}.nexedit_schema)
    AS schema_tables)
  ON (schema_tables.db_table = information_schema.tables.table_name
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)
  WHERE information_schema.tables.table_schema IS NULL
    AND schema_tables.db_table NOT LIKE 'nexedit_%'

GROUP BY information_schema.tables.table_name,schema_tables.db_table;
```

Comment: Re: "It's a quite long and complex query, sorry about that": Don't apologize for it -- fix it. Have you tried manually substituting in the value of `$db` and running the query at the MySQL command-line? Have you tried cutting out one branch of the `UNION` and seeing if the other branch triggers the error?

Comment: I haven't tried the latter suggestion, I'll report back when I have some results.

Comment: @ruakh I just tried to run the 2 union'd queries separately through phpMyAdmin. They both behave as expected, so the problem somehow seems to be the UNION command itself. It might be interesting to note that the second query doesn't (and isn't supposed to) return any results in this specific case (although it is necessary in other cases), would that impact the UNION in any way?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying in other ways? What happens if you remove the group-by in the second query? What happens if you remove one of the joins (and just use some fixed value, such as `NULL`, for any fields that depend on the join)? What happens if you remove the `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`? What happens if you remove some of the unnecessary pairs of parentheses?

Comment: (But to answer your question -- if MySQL is complaining about a syntax error, then it hasn't gotten anywhere the near the point of discovering whether the second query returns any rows, so no, that isn't the problem.)

Comment: Update: we've traced back the error to the second part of the query. It only happens with the right join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's unnecessary `)` here: `AS schema_tables)` Should be before `AS`

Comment: Well, you can't just remove the `)` without removing the `(` that it's paired with. The structure here is `JOIN ((SELECT ...) AS ...) ON (...)`: many more parentheses than necessary, but they're all perfectly balanced.

Comment: I added the extra parentheses while debugging the query and since it worked on most installs, I figured leaving them in there once I was done. As @ruakh mentioned, they're balanced. If I were to remove some extra parentheses, would that make the query more stable? Theoretically speaking it shouldn't matter, but maybe it does make a difference that I don't know of.

Comment: Actually, never mind. This fixed it after all. Removing one of the "(" before SELECT DISTINCT and the ")" before ON did the trick. So that's `(SELECT ...) AS ... ON (...)`. Thank you so much!